# autoNumeric JS text field get cleared after focus out

Tags: javascript, formatting, onfocus

I use autoNumeric js for thousand separation, after entering the value and focus out to another field entered value erased.  what will be the reason? 
I have used the following code.

```
jQuery("#job_no").autoNumeric('init', {
            aSep: '.',
            aDec: ',',
            aForm: true,
            vMax: '9999999',
            vMin: '-999999'
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The version you are using looks pretty old and is not supported anymore, since the jQuery dependency has been dropped in `v4.0.0`.

You should try the [latest stable](https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/releases/tag/v4.1.0) `v4.1.0` with was released today, with a fix for input that got cleared on blur on Android Chrome.